# How to add special characters as entity in API.AI

Tags: entity, dialogflow-es

I would like to add an entity in api.ai that appears as follows in the CSV format
"B@","B@","Bank"
I keep getting the error saying I cannot add this entity. Anyone knows how to get API.ai to work with unicode or other special characters in entities?

```
{ id: '3a99a9a7-71f6-4b8b-9c22-8047d8c8ec44',
  timestamp: '2017-12-19T11:24:56.77Z',
  lang: 'en',
  status:
   { code: 400,
     errorType: 'bad_request',
     errorDetails: 'Error parsing Entity \'currencies\': Syntax Error in input \'B@\'. Incorrect token at position 2. Maybe you did not close round, curly or square bracket.',
     webhookTimedOut: false } }
```

This is the exact error I get, how do I B@ as the entity name if i wanted to

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's strange b@ entity is not allowed but b@b is allowed. From this it's clear @ symbol is somehow allowed but misinterpreted while parsing.

When I include html unicode for @ inside square brackets - b[U+0040] and b[html Unicode for @] as entity like below it triggered the corresponding entity.

[image: Add html uicode inside square brackets]

And I received in backend webhook as well. For unicode of symbols follow this link https://unicode-table.com/

[image: Webhook]

You could also do this with @sys.any without creating the entity and verify it at the webhook if it is b@ or not but that is an inefficient way I guess.

Comment: actually i have an entity called currencies which is full of symbols like btc ltc etc, b@ is one such symbol, i am looking to trigger an intent currency to currency to facilitate conversions and am stuck here since b(at) cannot be added

Comment: try wrapping it with square brackets b[unicode-symbol-of-@] and add it along with other currency symbols.

Comment: just tried some stuff around, the problem with the unicode approach is that if you try searching for b@ it doesnt find anything even though the entity has been added, it was a nice discovery on your end though but i think the unicode values are messing things up

Comment: I tried using your concept of writing [unicode-symbol-of-special-character] within square brackets. I want recognition of <(less than), >(greater than), =(equal to) signs as entities. But that didn't work in DialogFlow. I am still looking to find a way to do this.